# How can I regsvr32 my controls at a user (HKEY_CURRENT_USER) level?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, regsvr32

I want to register my controls at user level, kindly guide me how can I achive this with regsvr32.

If its not possible with regsvr32 please tell any alternative way to achive this.

Comment: `regsvr32` does not control the registration process. It [only calls `DllRegisterServer`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/11/10/10235540.aspx) of the given library, and the library itself performs registration.

Comment: @grawity, thanks for your reply, but how can I register my dll only for current user so that other user can't use this.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
regsvr32 /n /i:user name.dll
```

Comment: Care to explain what this does or how it works @Sune?

Comment: it registers the dll for the current user?!

Comment: I meant it rather that it would be helpful if you explained the syntax, what each part means, so others will know which options they might need

Comment: That only works if the specified DLL happens to take an argument (specifically named `user`). It is not a universal solution (especially since few DLLs take arguments to `DllInstall` at all, let alone that one). It might work for the OP, but it depends on their DLL, and even then, it may require a different argument.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [tool named **RegSvrEx** out on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3505/RegSvrEx-An-Enchanced-COM-Server-Registration-Util) which seems to allow you just what you want.

The syntax is:

```
RegSvrEx [/u] [/c] servername
```

With

```
/u - Unregister server
/c - Register or unregister (if /u is also specified) only for the current user
servername - Full path of the server .exe or .dll
```

See the [comments on the article's page](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3361407/Solution-to-problems-with-Windows-Vista-Windows-7-.aspx) on how to change the code for using with Windows Vista and above.